# How to access Oracle Apex Application over a local network?

Tags: database, oracle, networking, oracle-apex

I just want my Oracle Apex Application along with Database installed in PC-1, and then rest of PC's just access this application via LAN cable or Wi-Fi. How can I do it without using any hosting service?

And also want to know about the ORDS Restful Services. How to configure it for the other client systems and for the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Apex doesn't differ to any other wesite from this point of view.

You need to setup Apex/ORDS listeners, and then you can access it from your local network like :

```
IpOfThePCWhereApexIsInstalled:PortConfiguredWithApex/Apex
```

for Example

```
192.178.160.1:443/Apex  (if Apex is configured on port 443)
192.178.160.1:80/Apex   (if Apex is configured on port 80)
```

This way, the browser will search for the ip inside your local network and access it.

Comment: And the OP needs to consider that since he says he is installing on a PC (as opposed to a real server) that the IP address might be a moving target ... dynamically assigned from a DHCP server.